The type or name Workspace does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Visualstudio
I am trying to write a visual studio extension code to open a folder as mention in the API's Documentattion through using
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Worspace ;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.Settings;


The type or name Workspace does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Visualstudio
VS version 2022

I have also tried
_dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", "pathToFolder");

but I do not have development tool environment object
Is this a version problem or I am missing something?

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Worspace ;  There is a typo here "worspace" <-> "wor k space" . Could you clarify if the typo is in your code or just in the question? I'd recommend using only copy-pasting for both showing the code in Stack Overflow and the error message (as the error message does not seem to have the typo).
